# Get all data out from enum type

Tags: java, java-8

I have an `enum` named `Product`, each item override its abstract method which returns a `Manufacture` instance:

```
public enum Product {
     FOO {
       @Override
       Manufacture getManufacture(){
            return // a instance of Manufacture
       }
     }

     BAR {
       @Override
       Manufacture getManufacture(){
            return // another instance of Manufacture
       }
     }

    abstract Manufacture getManufacture();
}
```

(`Manufacture` is another class I created, but it is not important to see its details for this question)

Question 1:
In another class, I want to get a set of manufacture (`Set<Manufactore>`) out from the `Product` enum.  What is the easiest way in Java 8 ?

Question 2:
What about a `List<Manufacture>` ?

Question 3:
How to do the same for Question 1 & 2 inside the enum class if it is possible?

Comment: _out from the Product enum_ you mean from an enum constant? or from the enum class itself? show an example of the method signature you have in mind

Comment: In quesiton 1 & 2 I mean get that from another class outside the enum class. In question 3, I mean get that from a function inside the enum class if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stream.of(Product.values()).map(Product::getManufacture)` returns `Stream<Manufacture>`. Now you can call on it

1. `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` to get `Set<Manufacture>`
2. or `.collect(Collectors.toList())` to get `List<Manufacture>`.

Edit: 3rd point

If you want to access those collections from inside enum you can store them in some private static field and use getters to them. To avoid letting clients modify those collections you can either each time return copy of them in getter for instance via `return new ArrayList(manufactureSet);` or you can make that collection immutable and then return it like

```
private static Set<Manufacture> manufacturers = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
        Stream.of(values()).map(MyEnum::getManufacture).collect(Collectors.toSet())
);

public static Set<String> getManufacturers() {
    return manufacturers;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `Stream.of(Product.values())` will return a `Stream<Product[]>`.

Comment: @Avi What makes you think so? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...- uses varargs which should handle it nicely.

Comment: You're right, you're right. I just tested it, and it works. +1 for teaching me something new. Stream.of() only goes badly on primitive arrays.

Comment: Added a 3rd question in OP.

Comment: @Leem.fin Are you facing any problem while using this code inside your enum?

Comment: To put it in Product, just define a static method: `public static List/Set<Manufacture> getManufactures() { ........ }` where you return one of the List/Set<Manufacture> as defined above.

Comment: @Avi, for primitive arrays, you may use `IntStream.of()`, `DoubleStream.of()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
Arrays.stream(Product.values()).map(Product::getManufacture).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

List:

```
Arrays.stream(Product.values()).map(Product::getManufacture).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: That won't compile.